# Laravel 5 Route Strange Behaviour

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I have a Laravel site set up on a Homestead box, so I'm accessing it on `sitename.app:8000`. I have a route called "news" but when I try to go to  `sitename.app:8000/news` I get oddly bounced out to `sitename.app/news/`.

If I change the routename to "news2" I can access the desired controller action as per normal at `sitename.app:8000/news2`. So somehow it's "news" itself that has become uncooperative - and I'm pretty sure that we aren't even getting as far as the NewsController, when I try to access that url.

Can anyone work out from these symptoms what might be going wrong? One "news"-related change I made at some point was to add `$router->model('news', "App\News");` in the `boot` method of the RouteServiceProvider, but removing this doesn't seem to make the difference.

ETA: People keep asking for the routes.php file. I can literally remove everything from the file except

```
Route::get('news', function() {
    return "hello world";
});

Route::get('news2', function() {
    return "hello world";
});
```

and /news2 will work but /news will bounce me out. So I remain pretty convinced that the problem is somewhere deeper than routes.php...

Comment: Include you route definitions.

Comment: @MattBurrow for the sake of simplicity I can remove everything in routes.php except Route::get('news', 'NewsController@test'). Still redirects to the non-port-8000 sitename.app. Any other route I've tried that is not 'news' does not lose the port in this way. The contents of NewsController.php don't seem to matter either  - even if I rename that, we still find ourselves at the nonexistent sitename.app/news/.

Comment: Whoops! I wrongly claimed this was Laravel 4 (which in fairness I was working on, in a different project, at the same time), but it's the new version. Hope that didn't send anyone off on the wrong track, infinite apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked out what boneheaded action of mine had been causing this behaviour!

I had created a folder in /public named "news"... i.e. with the same name as an important route. Not sure exactly what havoc this was wreaking behind the scenes for Laravel every time a request for /news was being made, but one can assume it was nothing good.

Advice for anyone tearing their hair out over a route that "mysteriously doesn't work" - check your public folder for possible collisions!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue [Larvel missing port](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1833)

The easiest way to solve this problem is to go to `public/index.php` and set the `SERVER_PORT` value.

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 8000;
```

Don't forget to set the base url in the config if you are using links on website, the url generator uses the base-url defined in the config.

Last option is to change the vm portfoward in VagrantFile to point to port 80 and use port 80 for your app.

Comment: Hmm, looks like useful areas to investigate but I still don't really get why it would only be happening on a single route...

Comment: can you post your controller + routes file?